# Cannot pass model data from aggregation binding to block for lazy loading in xml view

Tags: sapui5, lazy-loading

I'm building an SAPUI5 Fiori application from the project template "SAP Fiori Master-Detail Application" in SAP Web IDE. I connect to an OData Service that gives me this nested structure (**bold text** represents a navigation property):

- File

  - Properties...
  - **ToRegister** (returns collection of Registers)

    - Properties...
    - **ToDocumentType** (returns collection of DocumentTypes)

      - Properties...
      - **ToDocument** (returns collection of Documents)

        - Properties...

Displaying data in the Detail View is very slow, so I'm trying to use [`sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout)'s lazy loading feature. For that, I have to extract parts of my view and put them into a custom block. This is accomplished by deriving from [`sap.uxap.BlockBase`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.BlockBase), according to [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageOnJSONWithLazyLoading/preview) ([code here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageOnJSONWithLazyLoading/code)). Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples that use aggregations/aggregation bindings.

I use XML Views. My Detail View looks like this:

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns="sap.uxap"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:m="sap.m">
    <ObjectPageLayout sections="{ToRegister}">
        <sections>
            <ObjectPageSection title="{RegisterName}" subSections="{ToDocumentType}">
                <subSections>
                    <ObjectPageSubSection title="{Description}" >
                        <blocks>
                            <m:List items="{ToDocument}">
                                <m:CustomListItem>
                                    ...code for displaying properties...
                                </m:CustomListItem>
                            </m:List>
                        </blocks>
                    </ObjectPageSubSection>
                </subSections>
            </ObjectPageSection>
        </sections>
    </ObjectPageLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

This code does **not** use custom blocks. This is the slow version, but it works and displays the data correctly. Notice that the bold navigation properties are placed in curly braces (e.g. `<m:List items="{ToDocument}">`).

For my custom block, I extracted the `<m:List>` part into a seperate view:

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns="sap.uxap"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:m="sap.m">
    <m:List items="{Documents}">
        <m:CustomListItem>
            ...code for displaying properties...
        </m:CustomListItem>
    </m:List>
</mvc:View>
```

Notice here that the property in the curly braces is not `{ToDocument}` anymore but `{Documents}`. That's because of the model mapping that has to be introduced in the original Detail View for this to work (see section *Model Mapping* in this [article](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/4527729576cb4a4888275b6935aad03a)). I modified the Detail View like this:

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns="sap.uxap"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:m="sap.m"
    xmlns:attachmentblock="pft7.blocks.FileAttachmentList">
    <ObjectPageLayout sections="{ToRegister}">
        ...
        <blocks>
            <attachmentblock:Block mode="Expanded">
                <ModelMapping 
                 externalModelName="ToDocumentType"
                 internalModelName="Documents"
                 externalPath="/ToDocument" />
            </attachmentblock:Block>
        </blocks>
        ...
    </ObjectPageLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

It's pretty much the same. I added the xml namespace `attachmentblock` (which points to my custom block) and used it to replace the `<m:List>` child of `<blocks>`. Notice the attribute `internalModelName` of the `<ModelMapping>` node. It can be freely chosen and just has to be the same as the model name used in the block's view.

**Finally, the problem**: With this modification, my Detail View does not display the document properties anymore. Instead, it just displays the text "No data". I added some dummy text and it was properly displayed in my Detail View, so the actual inclusion of the custom block itself seems to work.

**I suspect** that I got the `<ModelMapping>` part wrong, but I don't know how to set the attributes correctly. I couldn't find any examples that use aggregations and navigation properties for this, so I'm pretty clueless. The console does not log any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether it works if you use an “Object Page with LazyLoading without blocks” as seen [in this sample here?](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageLazyLoadingWithoutBlocks/preview)

In addition to this, you might also want to check on the reasons for the slow “Display of Detail View” via OData service.
Very often this is caused by long database access times.
If your backend is an R/3-ABAP system, you might want to check your OData service with an SQL-Trace (transaction ST05)
for long database response times caused by unnecessary requests or missing indexes.

Comment: I had the same thoughts yesterday and checked those things. According to Chrome, the request that performs the actual OData call takes just 166 ms - but it takes at least one or two seconds after that before anything is displayed.

I've also tried the other example that you linked in your answer, but I'm stuck there, too: The ObjectPageSubSection needs an ID (according to [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLazyLoader)) and in the example, all subsections have different IDs. I don't know how to do that with aggregations. Trying `id="myID"` also yields no data.

Comment: Sorry, for clarification: Using the ObjectPageLazyLoader doesn't actually display the text "NoData". Rather, the ObjectPageSubSections have no content at all.

Comment: It seems you don't use the “growing” feature in your List.
Here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.List says:
“The List control provides a container for all types of list items.
For mobile devices, the recommended limit of list items is 100 to assure proper performance. To improve initial rendering of large lists, use the "growing" feature.”
See this sample: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrowing/preview

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a working sample in a tool like https://plnkr.co/ ?
This might help debugging the issue.
As the OData service itself does not seem to be the issue, you might use a json-file with sample data or maybe even a Northwind service in this tool.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the growing feature, I didn't know that. I don't think this is the issue though, because my lists currently have only up to 3 items. I'll try setting up a plunkr this evening. I'm actually in Walldorf right now at the SAP Cloud Platform Developer Bootcamp, so I don't have too much time on my hands ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get my plunkr running. I tried stripping my demo down to the relevant core aspects and tried builing my plunkr according to [this one](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/xhEuwa), but it keeps throwing a huge pile of errors at me in the console. I don't have the time to get this to run, and after more than a week of trying I'll have to admit... this whole thing is a very frustrating experience. I don't know if there's anything else you could suggest - I guess I'll try to find another way to build this app.